# How to get build mode Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, configuration

I am building vue app, and created custom build mode for staging, by creating new `.env.staging` file, and to use this new env file:

```
yarn build --mode staging --dest dist
```

Now in `vue.config.js` I want to set the `publicPath` based on the mode, something like that:

```
module.exports = {
   publicPath: <mode> === "staging" ? "/web/" : "/"
};
```

Unfortunately I can not use `NODE_ENV`, because also for staging it should be set to `production` because `vue-cli` depend on this.